# write for stopword file txt on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, preprocessor, stop-words

```
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import StopWordRemoverFactory
factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
stopword = factory.create_stop_word_remover()
file = open('dataset/filter.txt', 'r')
for data in file:
    stop = stopword.remove(data)
    print(stop)
```

I have a problem with the stopword process on the txt file I keep on `dataset/filter.txt`. I'm still confused how to save the stopword process into the new file.

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too clear what you are trying to accomplish, but here is some general advice for using files. Let me know if you edit your question and we can try help you better.

When using files it is best practice to use the `with` context manager:

Read from file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # do stuff
```

Writing files (same, just use `f.write()`):

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_data_to_be_written)
```

And you can use either the `w` mode (instead of `r` for read) or the `a` if you only want to append and be sure you won't overwrite anything that was written before.